# detect LiveQuery connected clients on parse Server

Tags: parse-platform

how do i can detect when client connects via liveQuery to parse server.
I want to updata some data in MongoDB on client's Disconnect Event by Server.
Log display on Server but how i can call some function after detection of this event.

I am using self hosted Parse SErver.
[image: connect client lists on server]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Parse.Cloud.onLiveQueryEvent( ({event, clients, subscriptions, error}) => {
  if (event !== 'ws_disconnect') {
    return;
  }
  // Do your magic
});
```

In case you were wondering, these are the currently emitted events:

- connect
- subscribe
- unsubscribe
- ws_connect
- ws_disconnect
- ws_disconnect_error

"connect" differs from "ws_connect", the former means that the client completed the connect procedure as defined by Parse livequery protocol, where "ws_connect" just means that a new websocket was created.